# Open url with window.open and add HTML

Tags: javascript

I want to open a window like so:

```js
var myWindow = window.open("https://google.com");
```

and then add html or js. For example, when you open the tab after clicking a button, added JS would run `alert()` and give you an alert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot modify the website's content that has a different origin from yours.

Check the documentation of the `window.open`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#return_value

and specifically, this part

> **Return value**
>
> A WindowProxy object. The returned reference can be used
> to access properties and methods of the new window as long as it
> complies with the same-origin policy security requirements.